# MS SQL Server - Table Dependency Hierarchy Group

Tags: sql-server, dependencies, foreign-keys

I have a database with approx 500 tables and there are lot of foreign key relationships among these tables.

I need to form the groups of related tables together i.e one group is not related to any other group all the related tables should come in one group.

For ex:-
There are four tables T1, T2, T3 and T4.

T1 and T2 have a relationship and T3 and T4 have a relationship. So i can insert T1 and T2 in one group and T3 and T4 in another group.

Comment: You have to solve a network problem to achieve this, and I think it is far from trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Which SQL server are you using?

```
select O.name as [Object_Name], C.text as [Object_Definition]
from sys.syscomments C
inner join sys.all_objects O ON C.id = O.object_id
--where C.text like '%table_name%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hierarchical query on sys.foreign_keys that should get you pretty close to what you're looking for.

```
WITH cte AS (
    -- find tables that are parents, but are not children themselves

    SELECT [fk].[referenced_object_id] AS [child_id], 
        NULL AS [parent_id],
        CAST(CONCAT('/', [fk].[referenced_object_id], '/') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS h,
        1 AS l
    FROM sys.[foreign_keys] AS [fk]
    WHERE [fk].[referenced_object_id] NOT IN (
        SELECT [parent_object_id]
        FROM sys.[foreign_keys]
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT child.[parent_object_id],
        [child].[referenced_object_id] AS [parent_id],
        CAST(CONCAT(parent.[h], child.[parent_object_id], '/') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [h],
        parent.l + 1 AS l
    FROM cte AS [parent]
    JOIN sys.[foreign_keys] AS [child]
        ON [parent].[child_id] = child.[referenced_object_id]
),
hier AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        OBJECT_NAME([cte].[child_id]) AS [child],
        object_name([cte].[parent_id]) AS [parent],
        h, 
        --CAST([cte].[h] AS HIERARCHYID) AS h
        l

    FROM cte
)
SELECT [hier].[child] ,
       [hier].[parent] ,
       [hier].[h]--.ToString()
FROM [hier]
ORDER BY 
    l, h -- breadth-first search
    --h, l -- depth-first search
    --h.GetLevel(), h -- breadth-first search; hierarchyid
    --h, h.GetLevel() -- depth-first search; hierarchyid
```

You'll note that I included two order by clauses. Each have their uses. Assume that you have the following disconnected graphs of foreign keys: (a → b → c), (d → e → f). Using the first order by clause will return rows in the following order: a, d, b, e, c, f. That is, all of the top-level elements first, followed by the tier two elements, etc. The second order by clause will return them in the order of a, b, c, d, e, f (or maybe d, e, f, a, b, c; depending on the object ids for a and d). The idea here is that you fully exhaust one disconnected graph before moving onto the next one.

One note is that I'm fairly sure that the above doesn't take self-referential foreign keys into account. If that's important to you, I'd deal with those as a separate action (i.e. fully populate those first, then find the non-self-referential relationships using the above).

I also left a comment or two in there for making a hierarchyid solution work. in the `hier` cte, use the casting of `h` to hierarchyid instead of h and then use the order by clauses that take advantage of that. None of that is necessary, but could be a good first exposure to hierarchyid.